# OxyPlot Mono for Android (aka Xamarin.Android) Misplaced Draw. (Stacked Column Series)

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, oxyplot

I'm using OxyPlot Library, and I'm trying to show a Stacked Column Chart, but it is rendered wrong.

Here is a mockup of how the chart should be:

[image: Expected Stacked Bar Chart]

Here is how I do create the PlotModel:

```
private void InitWidget ()
{

    _goalsPlotModel = new PlotModel ("Metas") {
        LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Outside,
        LegendPosition = LegendPosition.BottomCenter,
        LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Horizontal,
        LegendBorderThickness = 0
    };

    SelectedChannel = new ListOfValue ();
    SelectedProduct = new Product ();

    SelectedChannel.Code = string.Empty;
    SelectedProduct.ProductCode = string.Empty;

    LoadFilters ();
    Refresh ();
}
```

Here is how I add the Series:

```
private void FillGoalsPlotModel ()
{
    _goalsPlotModel.Series.Clear ();
    _goalsPlotModel.Axes.Clear ();

    var goals = new ColumnSeries {
        Title = "Goals",
        FillColor = OxyColors.Orange,
        IsStacked = true,
        StrokeColor = OxyColors.Black,
        StrokeThickness = 1
    };

    var sales = new ColumnSeries {
        Title = "Sales",
        FillColor = OxyColors.LightGreen,
        IsStacked = true,
        StrokeColor = OxyColors.White,
        StrokeThickness = 1
    };

    var surplus = new ColumnSeries {
        Title = "Surplus",
        FillColor = OxyColors.Cyan,
        IsStacked = true,
        StrokeColor = OxyColors.Black,
        StrokeThickness = 1
    };

    var categoryAxisForMonths = new CategoryAxis { 
        Position = AxisPosition.Bottom 
    };

    var valueAxis = new LinearAxis (AxisPosition.Left) { 
        MinimumPadding = 0, 
        MaximumPadding = 0.06, 
        AbsoluteMinimum = 0 
    };


    foreach (IGoal goal in _goals) {

        if (goal.GetSales () > goal.GetGoalValue ()) {
            sales.Items.Add (new ColumnItem { Value = goal.GetGoalValue () });
            surplus.Items.Add (new ColumnItem { Value = goal.GetSurplus () });
        } else {
            sales.Items.Add (new ColumnItem { Value = goal.GetSales () });
            goals.Items.Add (new ColumnItem { 
                Value = goal.GetGoalValue() - goal.GetSales ()  
            });
        }
    }

    foreach (var month in GetMonths()) {
        categoryAxisForMonths.Labels.Add (month);
    }


    _goalsPlotModel.Series.Add (sales);
    _goalsPlotModel.Series.Add (goals);
    _goalsPlotModel.Series.Add (surplus);

    _goalsPlotModel.Axes.Add (categoryAxisForMonths);
    _goalsPlotModel.Axes.Add (valueAxis);


    RaisePropertyChanged (() => GoalsPlotModel);
}
```

And here is how it is rendered:

[image: Misplaced Stacked Column Series]

If I set `IsStacked` to `false` it just draw a Vertical BarChart, but every bar bottom is at `y = 0` as expected, but if `IsStacked` is set to `true` every bar bottom is at different `y` values.

Is it a bug in the Oxyplot for Mono for Android Renderer?
Or just I am doing something wrong? (if yes, what I'm doing wrong?)

Comment: Hey Alberto, can you post some input (could be dummy) I could test against?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following works for me.
I'll attach some screenshots after the code, but I think your problem was the way you were adding the points to the stacks.

You are adding 2 points (or columns really) on each case, but you need to assign values to 3 (the third one being zero). Otherwise The results will keep stacking until you get 3, and nothing will seem correct.

My Xaml is straight forward:

```
<oxy:Plot Model="{Binding MyPlotModel}" />
```

Then I call this method from my constructor, to create and set the model:

```
private void SetPlot()
{
    var model = new PlotModel("Metas")
    {
        LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Outside,
        LegendPosition = LegendPosition.BottomCenter,
        LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Horizontal,
        LegendBorderThickness = 0
    };

    var goals = new ColumnSeries {
        Title = "Goals",
        FillColor = OxyColors.Orange,
        IsStacked = true,
        StrokeColor = OxyColors.Black,
        StrokeThickness = 1
    };

    var sales = new ColumnSeries {
        Title = "Sales",
        FillColor = OxyColors.LightGreen,
        IsStacked = true,
        StrokeColor = OxyColors.White,
        StrokeThickness = 1
    };

    var surplus = new ColumnSeries {
        Title = "Surplus",
        FillColor = OxyColors.Cyan,
        IsStacked = true,
        StrokeColor = OxyColors.Black,
        StrokeThickness = 1
    };

    var categoryAxisForMonths = new CategoryAxis { 
        Position = AxisPosition.Bottom 
    };

    var valueAxis = new LinearAxis (AxisPosition.Left) { 
        MinimumPadding = 0, 
        MaximumPadding = 0.06, 
        AbsoluteMinimum = 0 
    };

    // Creating random data for 12 months
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        //var goal = 10;   // if you want a set goal, use this
        var goal = RandomHelper.RandomInt(8, 11); // otherwise use this
        var actualsales = RandomHelper.RandomInt(5, 15);

        if (actualsales > goal)
        {
            sales.Items.Add  (new ColumnItem( goal               ));
            surplus.Items.Add(new ColumnItem( actualsales-goal   ));
            goals.Items.Add  (new ColumnItem( 0                  ));
        }
        else
        {
            sales.Items.Add  (new ColumnItem( actualsales        ));
            goals.Items.Add  (new ColumnItem( goal - actualsales ));
            surplus.Items.Add(new ColumnItem( 0                  ));
        }

        // Next will create jan - dec in the labels
        categoryAxisForMonths.Labels.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames[i]);

    }

    model.Series.Add (sales);
    model.Series.Add (goals);
    model.Series.Add (surplus);

    model.Axes.Add (categoryAxisForMonths);
    model.Axes.Add (valueAxis);

    MyPlotModel = model;
}
public PlotModel MyPlotModel { get; set; }
```

RandomHelper is a simple class to assist getting randoms:

```
public static class RandomHelper
{
    private static readonly Random RandomSeed = new Random();

    public static int RandomInt(int min, int max)
    {
        return RandomSeed.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

And here are the results:

[image: Fixed goal]

[image: Random goal]

The funny lines are the result of the borders on empty columns, but you'll be able to figure it out :)